# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError on AIX

Tags: java, aix

I have Compiled a jar file using JDK 1.6.0 to match the java version in the server. And when I execute `java -jar Myjarfile.jar` the programs runs well. I have then set up a Cron Job to execute the same file and now I am getting `UnsupportedClassVersionError` in my `/var/spool/mail/username` and of course the jar file is not executing using cron job. I find this very strange. I have run out of reasons as to why this would happen. What else should I check?

**UPDATE: I have checked JAVA_HOME s set correctly**

Comment: Have you checked for other JREs/JDKs? It's most likely running the command with a JRE < 1.6. The cron user has different settings than your user, hence the discrepancy.

Comment: @OP: As a start, read this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/frequently-repeated-question-request-problems-4175605430/#post5707383 Also, add this line into the cron-script: `which java; java -version` Plus: `echo $CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments.. java runtime being picked up is lower than your compiled jdk version. (difficult to point to the exact reason why it is being picked from the info given above).

What you could do is provide the absolute jdk path in your cron command.. i.e. inplace of just ***java -jar Myjarfile.jar***, provide something like

/usr/lib/jdk6/../java -jar Myjarfile.jar.